# Basic Auth Send API_KEY to php api - REACTJS

Tags: php, reactjs

I am sending the username and password to the PHP api with the API_KEY in the .env file. How do I get the user name before the semicolon as the password after the comma in Api? I could not run it with the current code I wrote. I'm using basic auth

**.env**

```
API_KEY=...:...
```

**REACT CODE**

```
import {decode as atob, encode as btoa} from 'base-64'
import { API_KEY } from 'dotenv'
import axios from 'axios';

axios.get('...php', { crossdomain: true } , {

 headers: {
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  'Authorization': 'Basic ' + `${btoa(`${API_KEY}`)}`           
 }
})
      .then(res => { ... })
```

**PHP**

```
 $AUTH_USER = '...';
 $AUTH_PASS = '...';

            if (! empty($_SERVER['REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']))
            {
                preg_match('/^Basic\s+(.*)$/i', $_SERVER['REDIRECT_HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], $AUTH_PASS);
                
                $str = base64_decode($AUTH_PASS[1]);
                
                list( $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] ) = explode(':', $str);
            }

            $has_supplied_credentials = !(empty($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && empty($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']));

            $is_not_authenticated = (
                !$has_supplied_credentials ||
                $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] != $AUTH_USER || $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']   != $AUTH_PASS
            );

            if ($is_not_authenticated) {
                header('HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required');
                header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Access denied"');
                exit;
            }
```

Comment: How are you running PHP? Is it plain PHP, no framework?

Comment: We run it in plain PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either write:

```js
const usernameAndPassword = 'a:b'
axios.get('https://some_url', {
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(usernameAndPassword),
  },
})
```

Or,

```js
axios.get('https://some_url', {
  auth: {
    username: 'a',
    password: 'b',
  },
})
```

Both are same; will send exact same request headers:

[image: headers]

To read the `API_KEY` i.e. username password from [env](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) file, you should name it as `REACT_APP_API_KEY` and then you can use it in your code as `process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY`.

Comment: I would suggest you to use [postman](https://www.postman.com/product/rest-client/) to test your APIs to make sure that PHP code is correct. I remember very less of PHP code now. You may tag this question with [tag:php], so that php users will also see it.

Comment: I can run it with POSTMAN, but reactjs doesn't validate

Comment: How are you running it in postman? Is it GET, POST etc etc? Can you tell me how you tested it on Postman?